# Prolog regarding list manipulation

Tags: list, prolog

statement:

```
value(engine,2000).
value(frame,605).
vehicle(motorbike,[engine,frame]).
```

how to write prolog predicate `total(X)`. X is your total sum for motorbike.

I was unable to relate value of engine=2000 plus value of frame=605 that should return answer 2605 if i consult total(motorbike).

Comment: i just create another statement and rules.from there i create the prolog predicate which is too 'lazy' easy just because i can't relate it. just like this: statement: 'vehicle(motorbike,2605).' rule:'total(x):- vehicle(X,Y).'   simple like that and wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[aggregation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) it's your friend:

```
total(Kind, X) :-
   vehicle(Kind, Parts),
   aggregate(sum(Price), Part^(member(Part, Parts), value(Part, Price)), X).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that does the summation explicitly if you don't have the `aggregate` predicate that CapelliC shows:

```
% This says total is sum of the parts

total( Item, Amt ) :-
    vehicle( Item, PartList ),
    sum_parts( PartList, 0, Amt ).

% This says the sum of the parts is the sum of current part in list plus the sum
% of the rest

sum_parts( [Part|PartList], Acc, Amt ) :-
  value( Part, PartAmt ),   % This statement will relate the part to its price for you
  Acc1 is Acc + PartAmt,    % This will accumulate the price to the running total
  sum_parts( PartList, Acc1, Amt ).
sum_parts( [], Amt, Amt ).
```

Comment: Instead of going via sum_parts/2, why don't you call sum_parts/3 from total/2 directly?

Comment: @Joost, yes, I could. I guess I was thinking of `sum_parts` as it's own, stand-alone sum predicate without the initial accumulator. I made that adjustment in the answer since it makes perfect sense in this context.